# Edit header file with awk

Tags: header, awk

I have a file that is white-space separated value, i need to convert this into:

```
header=tab separated, 
records=" ; " separated (space-semicolon-space)
```

what i'm doing now is:

```
cat ${original} | awk 'END {FS=" "} { for(i=1; i<=NR; i++) {if (i==1) { OFS="\t"; print $0; } else { OFS=";" ;print $0; }}}' > ${new}
```

But is working only partly, first, it produces millions of lines, while the original ones has about 90000.

Second, the header, which should be modified here:

```
if (i==1) { OFS="\t"; print $0; }
```

Is not modified at all,

Another option would be by using sed, i can get that job to be done partially, but again the header remains untouched:

```
cat ${original} | sed 's/\t/ ;/g' > ${new}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line should change all the separator in file

```
 awk -F'\t' -v OFS=";" '$1=$1' file
```

this will leave header untouched:

```
 awk -F'\t' -v OFS=";" 'NR>1{$1=$}1' file
```

this will **only** change the header line:

```
 awk -F'\t' -v OFS=";" 'NR==1{$1=$1}1' file
```

you could paste some example to let us know why your header was not modified.

Comment: Hi, the third option is what i ideally need, but its not working, try tthese steps: 1 echo "a b c d e r" > test ; awk -F" " -OFS="\t" 'NR==1{$1=$1}1' test

Comment: your line is convert spaces sep into TAB sep.

Comment: Thats indeed what i want for the header, but still, its printed as whitespace

Comment: @JBoy sorry, I had a typo in my answer. `-v` was missing just now. try it now pls.